# Как получить данные из созданного элемента

Tags: java, swing

Реализую что-то типа таблицы, в которой ячейки сделаны из JPanel. Каждая строка выглядит одинаково, а именно вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально на экране есть одна эта строка, а ниже кнопка добавления новой строки.
А теперь об этой самой строке:

При нажатии на кнопку с плюсом на поле рядом должен добавиться `JLabel`. Так же для всех полей нужны функции, которые забирают из них значения. Это все я реализовал, а теперь к проблеме -

В коде мне надо сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `name=add`  произошло добавление новой такой же строки. Ладно, допустим, я добавил на экран элемент таким образом

```
JPanel newAdd = new JPanel();
newAdd.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
newAdd.add(newIcon);

toAdd.add(newAdd);
```

Но как мне теперь обратиться к нему и после ввода даннх пользователем в нем забрать их в переменную?

Comment: Вы бы код показали, что ли, как реализовали.

Comment: может стоит вынести всю функциональность такой "строки" в отдельный объект и плодить их по мере необходимости

Comment: А если этих строк будет 1000? 1000 объектов?